# sed append multi-line string after matching a single line string

Tags: bash, sed, puppet

I'd like to use `sed` for this solution if possible.  Here's my situation:

I have a multi-line string that will given to `sed` by external means - probably puppet shell exec or bash script. The string looks like:

```
$string = 'blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n'
```

I'd like to run a `sed` command that appends this string after a match is found -

```
sed -i "/^\[org\/gnome\/login-screen\]/a banner-message-text='$string'" /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-mybanner
```

The trouble is that `sed` is interpreting the `\n` characters as newlines. Note, that I realize there the way I declare the `$string` variable inside the `sed` command may differ depending on how it is executed, but even hand typing the string on the command line produces a multiline output. So the file ends up looking like:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-text='blah blah blah
blablah
blah blah blah

'
banner-message-enable=true
```

This causes `dconf update` to throw an error.  I'm hoping to get the file to look like:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-text='blah blah blah\nblablah\nblah blah blah\n\n'
banner-message-enable=true
```

But I can't seem to get `sed` to stop itself from interpreting the `\n`'s.
Thanks!

**EDIT -** Complete context with implemented solution (@tom-fenech) using Puppet:

```
  $banner_msg = 'blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n'

  $comply_cmd = "find /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^banner-message-text=/d' || /bin/true && \
    (grep -q \"^\[org/gnome/login-screen\]\" /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-banner && \
    sed -i \"/^\[org\/gnome\/login-screen\]/a banner-message-text='\$(printf '%q' \"${banner_msg}\")'\" /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-banner) || \
    (echo -e \"\n\[org/gnome/login-screen]\" >> /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-banner && \
    echo \"banner-message-text='${banner_msg}'\" >> /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-banner)"

  $unless_cmd = "grep -q \"^banner-message-text='\$(printf '%q' \"${banner_msg}\")'$\" /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/99-banner"

  exec { 'gdm-banner-msg':
    path     => '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin',
    umask    => '022',
    provider => shell,
    command  => $comply_cmd,
    unless   => $unless_cmd,
    notify   => Exec['dconf-update'],
  }
```

Thank you all!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140763/replace-n-by-a-newline-in-sed-portably

Comment: All three answers were useful, but I chose @tom-fenech because he logic and sequence of commands is more complex than posted.  Using his tactic allows me to set one `$string` variable with normal escape sequences, and use `printf '%q'` when I need to run `grep` or `sed`, but also use the original when I need to run `echo` or `echo -e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` with the `%q` format specifier. This takes care of the escaping for you:

```
$ echo "$string"
blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n
$ printf '%q' "$string"
blah\ blah\ blah\\nblahblah\\nblah\ blah\ blah\\n\\n
```

From `man bash`:

> `%q`     causes `printf` to output the corresponding argument in a format
>   that can be reused as shell input.

This means that the spaces are backslash-escaped too but this does no harm.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
[org/gnome/login-screen]
$ sed "/^\[org\/gnome\/login-screen\]/a banner-message-text='$(printf '%q' "$string")'" file
[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-text='blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n'
```

Comment: You just convinced me to have a closer look at the format specifiers of `printf`. Thanks for this gem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your backslashes:

```
$ string='blah blah blah\\nblahblah\\nblah blah blah\\n\\n'
$ echo $string
blah blah blah\\nblahblah\\nblah blah blah\\n\\n
$ cat foo.txt
foo
baz
test

$ sed -i "/^foo/a bar='$string'" foo.txt 
$ cat foo.txt 
foo
bar='blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n'
baz
test

$
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare initial config file:

```
echo -e "[org/gnome/login-screen]\nbanner-message-enable=true"> /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-mybanner
cat /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-mybanner

[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-enable=true
```

Insert new banner message without interpreting \n characters:

```
string='blah blah blah\\nblahblah\\nblah blah blah\\n\\n'; sed -i "/^\[org\/gnome\/login-screen\]/a banner-message-text=\'$string\'" /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-mybanner
```

See the result:

```
cat /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-mybanner

[org/gnome/login-screen]
banner-message-text='blah blah blah\nblahblah\nblah blah blah\n\n'
banner-message-enable=true
```

*The point is:* put one **extra slash before** each \n in your string. This will prevent sed from interpreting \n character.

Comment: Thank you, I did do some experimenting to this end and the results between setting the string inside bash and setting it inside puppet were not consistent.  I'll add some more information on this topic to my question above.